# Fill NaN in Pandas DataFrame by selecting value from other DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am toying with the Titanic dataset and am trying to fill in the Age Values.
My dataframes look like:

```
 Dataframe df

    Survived  Pclass   Age  SibSp  Parch      Fare  male  Q  S   Title
0           0       3  22.0      1      0    7.2500     1  0  1      Mr
1           1       1  38.0      1      0   71.2833     0  0  0     Mrs
2           1       3  26.0      0      0    7.9250     0  0  1    Miss
3           1       1  35.0      1      0   53.1000     0  0  1     Mrs
4           0       3  35.0      0      0    8.0500     1  0  1      Mr
5           0       3   NaN      0      0    8.4583     1  1  0      Mr
```

And

```
DataFrame age_df
                    3        1        2
    Mr        28.7249  41.5805  32.7683
    Mrs       33.5152  40.8824  33.6829
    Miss      16.1232       30  22.3906
    Master    5.35083  5.30667  2.25889
    Don            40       40       40
    Rev       43.1667  43.1667  43.1667
    Dr             42    43.75     38.5
    Mme            24       24       24
    Ms             28       28       28
    Major        48.5     48.5     48.5
    Lady           48       48       48
    Sir            49       49       49
    Mlle           24       24       24
    Col            58       58       58
    Capt           70       70       70
    Countess       33       33       33
    Jonkheer       38       38       38
```

I want to fill the `df['Age']` missing values with the corresponding value from age_df based on `df['Title']` and `df['Pclass']`

I've come up with this but none of the NaNs get overwritten.

```
for tit in df['Title'].unique():
    for cls in [1,2,3]:
        df.loc[ (df['Age'].isna() == True) &
                (df['Title'] == tit) &
                (df['Pclass'] == cls)]['Age'] = age_df.loc[tit][cls]
```

Furthermore I don't think this should be done with a nested loop.
How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way may be to use `apply` with  `if` and `else` condition as below:

```
df['Age'] = df.apply(lambda row: age_df.loc[row.Title, row.Pclass] 
                                               if pd.isnull(row.Age) 
                                               else row.Age, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lookup`:

```
In [75]: s = pd.Series(age_df.lookup(df.Title, df.Pclass), index=df.index)    
In [76]: s
Out[76]: 
0    28.7249
1    40.8824
2    16.1232
3    40.8824
4    28.7249
5    28.7249
dtype: float64

In [77]: df.Age = df.Age.fillna(s)   
In [78]: df.Age
Out[78]: 
0    22.0000
1    38.0000
2    26.0000
3    35.0000
4    35.0000
5    28.7249
Name: Age, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using `loc[,]` instead of `loc[][]`

```
for tit in df['Title'].unique():
    for cls in [1,2,3]:
        df.loc[ (df['Age'].isna() == True) &
                (df['Title'] == tit) &
                (df['Pclass'] == cls), 'Age'] = age_df.loc[tit,cls]
```

I'm still curious about how it should be done without loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of one loop by just looping through the smaller number of `Pclass`, and then use the titles to map the values.

```
for col in age_df:
    mask = (df.Age.isnull()) & (df.Pclass==int(col))
    df.loc[mask, 'Age'] = df.loc[mask, 'Title'].map(age_df[col])

   Survived  Pclass      Age  SibSp  Parch     Fare  male  Q  S Title
0         0       3  22.0000      1      0   7.2500     1  0  1    Mr
1         1       1  38.0000      1      0  71.2833     0  0  0   Mrs
2         1       3  26.0000      0      0   7.9250     0  0  1  Miss
3         1       1  35.0000      1      0  53.1000     0  0  1   Mrs
4         0       3  35.0000      0      0   8.0500     1  0  1    Mr
5         0       3  28.7249      0      0   8.4583     1  1  0    Mr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `melt` to reshape your `age_df` to [tidy format](http://www.jeannicholashould.com/tidy-data-in-python.html)`, then`merge`and`fill`.

```
age_df = age_df.melt('Title', var_name='Pclass')
age_df[:4]
    Title   Pclass  value
0   Mr      3       28.7249
1   Mrs     3       33.5152
2   Miss    3       16.1232

df = df.merge(age_df, how='left')
idx = df.Age.isnull()
df.Age[idx] = df.value[idx]
```

This is not the shortest approach, but after reading all other answers. I still love mine.